# signal handler in child thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I tried to install SIGINT handler for the child thread in the code below. I expect the child thread to print hello when it receives SIGINT from the parent process. However, nothing comes out and the program exits immediately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct proxy_node_t{
    pthread_t sub_thread;
    pthread_t p_self;
}proxy_node;

proxy_node* proxy;

static void proxy_singnal_handler(){
    printf("Hello\n");
    return;
}

static void* t_consensus(void *arg){
    signal(SIGINT,proxy_singnal_handler);
    sleep(1);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    proxy = (proxy_node*)malloc(sizeof(proxy_node));
    proxy->p_self = pthread_self();
    pthread_create(&proxy->sub_thread,NULL,t_consensus,NULL);
    pthread_kill(proxy->sub_thread,SIGINT);
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf()` is not async-safe. You must not call it from a signal-handler. Also, you have a race between the created thread's invocation of `signal()` and the main thread's call to `pthread_kill()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems.

1) The signal handler signature is not correct. It should take an `int` whereas you define it with no parameter.
i.e.

```
static void proxy_singnal_handler(){
```

should be

```
static void proxy_singnal_handler(int sig){
```

2) You can't call functions that are not *async-signal-safe* from a signal handler (`printf()` in your case). See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for details. You can instead use `write(2)` to print that message:

```
printf("Hello\n");
```

can be:

```
write(1, "Hello\n", 6);
```

3) When *main* thread sends `SIGINT`, the `t_consensus` thread might not have even started. So, `signal()` may not have been installed yet. So, you need to make sure `signal()` is installed *before* `pthread_kill()` could send `SIGINT`.

---

Just to demonstrate it, I have added some sleep calls (see comments in the code). But please note that sleep() is *not* a good way to synchronization and if you intend to adapt this example then you should use a conditional variable instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct proxy_node_t{
    pthread_t sub_thread;
    pthread_t p_self;
}proxy_node;

proxy_node* proxy;

static void proxy_singnal_handler(int sig){
    write(1, "Hello\n", 6);
    return;
}

static void* t_consensus(void *arg){
    signal(SIGINT,proxy_singnal_handler);
    while(1); /* infinite loop */
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    proxy = (proxy_node*)malloc(sizeof(proxy_node));
    proxy->p_self = pthread_self();
    pthread_create(&proxy->sub_thread,NULL,t_consensus,NULL);
    sleep(2); /* delay to ensure signal handler is installed */
    pthread_kill(proxy->sub_thread,SIGINT);
    sleep(2); /* delay to ensure signal gets executed before the process exits */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your proposed code exhibits undefined behavior: `exit()` (or equivalently, returning from `main()`) is not thread-safe. I'd recommend a couple of semaphores.

Comment: @EOF `exit()` terminates any process, regardless of the number of threads.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: The C-standard doesn't actually say a lot about what happens to running threads when `exit()` is called. Even if we assume that `exit()` causes the equivalent to `pthread_cancel()` with asynchronous cancelability in the other threads, that's sill not safe by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @EOF C standard underspecifies it. POSIX is very clear though: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01

Comment: @EOF OP could let the thread exit gracefully instead of using an infinite loop or use _Exit/_exit instead.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: The only reference to threads I see on that page is about `_Exit()` or `_exit()`. Nothing substantial about what exactly happens to running threads when another thread calls `exit()`.

Comment: @EOF Start with [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) and read the description.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I have. I have not found anything substantial about what happens to other threads when `exit()` is called. If you know of any authoritative source, feel free to cite a sentence or two you consider relevant. Otherwise, I'd appreciate a bit less arrogance from you.

Comment: @EOF I would be interested to see your semaphore solution. _`exit()` is not thread-safe_ sounds like nonsense to me. `exit()` terminates a process, threads cannot exist without a process.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Done. Tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Maxim Egorushkin wanted to see a solution that exits gracefully and uses semaphores:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

typedef struct proxy_node_t{
    pthread_t sub_thread;
    pthread_t p_self;
}proxy_node;

proxy_node* proxy;

static void proxy_singnal_handler(int sig)
{
    write(1, "Hello\n", 6);
    return;
}

sem_t sema1;
sem_t sema2;

static void* t_consensus(void *arg)
{
  signal(SIGINT,proxy_singnal_handler);
  sem_post(&sema1);   /*notify main thread that signal-handler is installed*/
  sem_wait(&sema2);   /*ensure thread exists to be pthread_kill'ed, could use sigsuspend instead*/
  return NULL;
}
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  sem_init(&sema1, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&sema2, 0, 0);
  proxy = (proxy_node*)malloc(sizeof(proxy_node));
  proxy->p_self = pthread_self();
  pthread_create(&proxy->sub_thread,NULL,t_consensus,NULL);
  sem_wait(&sema1);    /*wait until the thread has installed the signal handler*/
  pthread_kill(proxy->sub_thread,SIGINT);
  sem_post(&sema2);    /*not strictly necessary if the thread uses sigsuspend*/
  pthread_join(proxy->sub_thread, NULL);
  free(proxy);         /*not strictly necessary before exiting*/
  sem_destroy(&sema1);
  sem_destroy(&sema2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first semaphore is used to wait for the child thread to start. The second is used to put that child thread to sleep and then cancel the thread on return from `sem_wait(&sema2)`. It is not clear what these semaphores have to do with `exit()` at all. Whereas you were concerned that `exit()` introduces a data race with something.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: The semaphores ensure an *order* to what happens: 1. main creates thread 2. thread installs signal handler 3. main sends signal to thread 4. thread exits 5. main exits. These events cannot happen in any other order anymore, so 1. The signal cannot accidentally terminate the process because the signal disposition is still default 2. The thread cannot have terminated before the signal is sent and finally 3. There is no concurrent thread running when main calls exit.